Bochner's formula
I am studying Bochner's formula formulated in the following way:
Let $(M,g)$ be oriented and $d$ the exterior derivative on forms. We have the Laplacian on forms $\Delta=d^*d+dd^*$ where $d^*$ is the $L^2$-dual of $d$. Additionally, we define for $\xi\in\Omega^1(M)$, $$\nabla^*\nabla\xi = -Tr(\nabla\nabla\xi) = -\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\nabla_{e_i}\nabla_{e_i}\xi-\nabla_{\nabla_{e_i}e_i}\xi\right)$$
as the trace of the second covariant derivative of (actually any section of any bundle) a 1-form. The $(e_i)$ constitute an orthonormal frame of $TM$. Now the Bochner formula is compactly written as $$\Delta\xi = \nabla^*\nabla\xi + Ric(\xi).$$
My only question is: What is $Ric(\xi)$? It must be a 1-form as the LHS of the equation is a 1-form. Moreover, I understand the Ricci tensor with respect to the metric $g$ but $Ric(\xi)$ seems to be a different object. Could someone give an intuitive idea of $Ric(\xi)$? Is it correct that its coordinate expression is something like
$Ric(\xi) = \xi_iR^i_jdx^{j}$ where $R^i_j$ are the usual components of the Ricci tensor?

Yes, I would say that your understanding is correct. The Ricci tensor is symmetric and twice-covariant, so using the metric we may see it as a self-adjoint endomorphism of the tangent bundle. Using the metric, convert the given 1-form to a vector field, and then feed it to the Ricci endomorphism to obtain another vector field. Now, use the metric to convert that back into a 1-form.

How can we see the Ricci tensor as a self-adjoint endomorphism with the metric?

If $(V,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ is any Euclidean space, the assignment taking a linear endomorphism $T\colon V\to V$ to the bilinear form $B\colon V\times V\to \Bbb R$ given by $B(v,w) = \langle Tv,w\rangle$ is an isomorphism between the space of all linear endomorphisms of $V$ and all bilinear forms on $V$. Then self-adjoint endomorphisms correspond to symmetric bilinear forms.
